# Is better way to make main layout than copy paste?

Tags: android, android-layout

As in title I'm not sure that my way to make main layout is good, because I need 10 objects like that one below. Is better way than copy paste it 10 times and then change all ids? With 4 these obejcts i have over 380 lines.

how does it should look

[image: how does it should look]

```
FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/upbar">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/waterBottles"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/x1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="x1"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/wm1"
    android:layout_below="@id/upbar">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/wm1img"
            android:src="@mipmap/jeden"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wm1img">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/wm1pb"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
                    android:background="#00686464"
                    android:indeterminate="false"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:progress="100"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/horizontalprogressbar" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:id="@+id/wm1mm"
                    android:text="566 decilion"/>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/wm1pb">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/wmbuy"
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/wm1img"
                            android:text="x1"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle1"
                            android:padding="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/wm1cost"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="10decilion"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/wm1time"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:id="@+id/wm1time"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle2"
                            android:text="1s"
                            android:gravity="center"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Anybody knows how to resolve that problem? I would be appreciated

Comment: you should use RecyclerView I think

Comment: You should separate the layout in a layout file, then be using a ```RecyclerView``` OR use the ```<include layout="@layout/your_item_layout.xml />``` in the main layout

Answer (score 0):

1) First you have to create one item file. your_item_layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/upbar">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/waterBottles"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


            <Button
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/x1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="x1"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

2) item file include on your MainActivity.xml file.

```
<LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">

             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>
             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>
             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>
             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>
             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>
             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>
             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>
             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>
             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>
             <include layout="@layout/your_item_layout"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Notes:- You can also use Recyclerview to set this type of layout.